# Is it possible to connect the new DELL 31.5-inch monitor (UP3216Q) at 3840x2160 to the new macbook pro (late 2016)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I don't know exactly how to match the MacBook Pro 2016 specs to this display to see if it would connect at the native resolution (full pixels) of the dell display.

[https://www.amazon.com/Dell-UltraSharp-UP3216Q-Screen-Monitor/dp/B016IBVKNU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016IBVKNU)

Where can I learn how to qualify a display with MacBook Pro 2016?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, as the [display supports DisplayPort 1.2](http://4k.com/monitor/dell-up3216q-review-32-inch-4k-ultra-hd-lcd-ultrasharp-monitor/) which is sufficient to drive 4K resolution at 60 Hz. Many vendors will sell appropriate adapters, though. I recommend you get a USB-C (or Thunderbolt 3) to DisplayPort adapter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018AX3HJO). You could also use Apple's USB-C to HDMI adapter, but that one [only supports 30Hz at 4K resolutions](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter).

The Dell has these ports:

- DP, mDP, HDMI (MHL), 4 x USB3 with one charging port, 1 x USB3 upstream, Media Card Reader

Apple has a very nice article covering all the implications of USB-C and Thunderbolt including links to what displays they know work at 60 Hz and 4k resolution. You will want to read that carefully as well.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256